# Can I show the quick replies everytime the user opens his messenger chat?

Tags: nlp, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to show the quick replies in messenger bot every time they open the conversation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can invoke an event to get your task done. event are used to invoke intents by an event name instead of a user query. you can define the event name in the intent and call to trigger that event from your back-end implementation. please check this for more information.

https://dialogflow.com/docs/events

also if you are creating a custom UI(won't work in your case) for the chat basically you can hard code whatever the reply you want as the first message. then it will appear always when the user open the conversation.